# (google prettify) syntax highlighting not working after call back

Tags: php, javascript, syntax-highlighting

The method work fine with single php file:

So in my html page I try to use js and call php file and highlighting the content by google prettify

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="googleprettify/prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="googleprettify/prettify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","callback_json.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
   </head>

  <body onload="prettyPrint()" >

  <button onclick="loadXMLDoc();">Get Data</button>
<div id="...">
<pre class='prettyprint;'> 
    function foo()
    {
        if (counter == 10)
            return;
        // it works!
    }</pre>
</div>



<div id="myDiv">
need to be replaced
</div>
 </body>

</html>
```

The first piece of code works just fine but when i call php file

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init();
  $url='someurl';
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  echo '<pre class="prettyprint;"> ';
  echo $data;
  echo "</pre>";?>
```

And the returning code can't be highlighted. I doubt there's problem with body onload="prettyPrint()" since the prettyprint() only run when the page loaded but I'm not sure about this. Or is there any problem with the code structures? Or is there anyway to load prettyprint function again without loading the whole page?

Comment: After adding new elements to the DOM, why do you expect that the prettify library notices the changes on it's own?

Comment: @hakre I realized I have a weird structure doing this. so I'm wondering if there's any better way to use the library...Should I include the directory in php file directly?

Comment: no, *after* you update the DOM, call `prettyPrint()` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you update the DOM, call `prettyPrint()` again, otherwise you only have inserted some 
new HTML, but the prettification did not run:

```
...
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      prettyPrint();
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: wow I tried this before but it didn't work for some reason. But your are right! Thanks!